# Format the SentOn to display only date

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to construct a filename from an Outlook item.

I have code to save the file with the date (from `mySelectedItem.SentOn`) in the filename .

I don't need hours, minutes and seconds, like "19062019 105228-from-to-subject".

```
Dim msgFileName As String
msgFileName = mySelectedItem.SentOn & "-" & _
              mySelectedItem.SentOnBehalfOfName & "-" & _
              mySelectedItem.To & "-" & _
              mySelectedItem.Subject
```

I only need "19062019-from-to-subject".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will Work

All you have to use `Format` function on the Date. 
Like `Format(date, "ddmmyyy")`

```
Dim msgFileName As String
msgFileName = Format(mySelectedItem.SentOn,"ddmmyyyy") & "-" & _
              mySelectedItem.SentOnBehalfOfName & "-" & _
              mySelectedItem.To & "-" & _
              mySelectedItem.Subject
```